# Any key press goes to line end while typing

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, typing, keypad

When I click any key my Acer Aspire 4736z win7 goes to end of that line.

Even if I select a  word and start to replace it another, courser goes to line end after the first key up.

Is it a virus or any system fault? I had done a system check and system scan using avast.

I cannot use short cut keys and so on. I don't know what this is?

Comment: I will assume you don't have any key mapping?

Comment: Perhaps you have a stuck key? That happens. When I get a stuck key, I just switch to a non-threatening program like Notepad and then press every "special" key: all those Insert, Home, Page Up, etc. keys. Perhaps your "end" key is stuck?

Comment: @Wally KEY IS NOT STUCK. I CHECKED.

Comment: @DaveRook WHAT IS KEY MAPPING, HOW TO DO IT

Comment: Please do not reply with capital letters! If you don't know what it is, then it probably isn't on! Any way, your question is unclear. Does this issue occur on on certain programs? If so, what programs?

Comment: @DaveRook Any way thank you all. It was keyboard issue. replaced  keyboard.

Comment: @Wally Any way thank you all. It was keyboard issue. replaced keyboard

Answer (score 0):

OP answers question in comments.  The issue was a faulty keyboard